# How can you make Google Home device respond without having me tell it

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, assistant

I would like to make google home say something on a event base, let say I am streaming live score results for football teams and would like Google Home to announce the results every time a team scores a goal.

Currently I am trying to use this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-home-push applying following command:

```
npm install --save google-home-push
```

but for some reason I was unable to install it in both windows and ubuntu. Different errors into two os. Looks like for me the package is missing something as it cannot be that it cannot work on any os.

Any idea how can I achieve such thing? Any other package or technique to achieve this.

Comment: I was not aware of `google-home-push`. Seems to not be an official library which is using hidden APIs to accomplish tasks. Can you provide the errors?

Comment: there were some issues with permissions on ubuntu, which I fixed and now I am able to use the library, interesting that it works quite well, but in other hand there is a vulnerability on a package, at least thats what the console says. I dont know what is that exactly as it says to review it manually. I will check more if I find some time.